# Clean code to do partial patch of domain class in Spring @PatchMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In Spring, I write code like this to process a PATCH request:

```
@PatchMapping(path="/{orderId}", consumes="application/json")
public Order patchOrder(@PathVariable("orderId") Long orderId, @RequestBody Order patch) {
    Order order = repo.findById(orderId).get();
    if (patch.getDeliveryName() != null) {
        order.setDeliveryName(patch.getDeliveryName());
    }
    if (patch.getDeliveryStreet() != null) {
        order.setDeliveryStreet(patch.getDeliveryStreet());
    }
    if (patch.getDeliveryCity() != null) {
        order.setDeliveryCity(patch.getDeliveryCity());
    }
    //...
    //Check all fields in Order class.
    return repo.save(order);
}
```

Obviously, there're at least two drawbacks here:

1. The code is not clean because of lots of null checking.
2. Even if abstracting null checking into a function, there're still problems when we change the definition of `Order` class. That is to say, when removing fields or adding new fields in `Order` class, this chunk of code also must be rewritten.

I know I can do some null checking in client-side like only sending nonnull fields to do a PATCH, but I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to do this? Like object mapping or some the other ways?

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's not clean - it's just repetitive. If you happen to change the definition of `Order`, I would think it's better that this part of the application is broken (at compile-time). In fact, if I changed a domain class and nothing breaks, I'd probably feel paranoid.

Comment: @Jai Wow, I think I've got the point. Seems like I've confused the 'not clean' and 'repetitive'.

Comment: @Patrick I do validation check in some case like form domain class. But in this situation, the null field in a PATCH request doesn't mean invalid, it may mean leaving this field untouched.

Comment: I also don't think that it's wrong. But one thing I would change is: `Order order = repo.findById(orderId).get();` to something more appropriate, like `orElseThrow()` and I'm also not a big fan of logic inside controllers classes. I'd prefer to call a service method and do the checking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first instead of checking just null like below:

```
if (patch.getDeliveryName() != null) {
    order.setDeliveryName(patch.getDeliveryName());
}
```

You can make it one line:

```
order.setDeliveryName(StringUtils.isEmpty(patch.getDeliveryName()) ? "" : patch.getDeliveryName());
```

Also using spring provided method checks for null and Empty values.

And for point **"b"** you can use below code:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(bean2, bean1);
```

add following dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new parameter type, like OrderPatch, with Optional fields. (Spring does the mapping to Optional for you). In the patchOrder() method body you can use Optional.orElse() with the value of the existing order as default, without if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the nullchecker in the setter:

```
  Order order = repo.findById(orderId).get();
  order.setByPatch(patch)
```

inside the class Order

```
  public void setByPatch(Patch patch){
    this.setDeliveryName(patch.getDeliveryName());
    this.setDeliveryStreet(patch.getDeliveryStreet());
    this.setDeliveryCity(patch.getDeliveryCity());
  }
```

then add to the setters a NullCheck...

===========================================
Or you can refer to:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

And add a @Valid to the Order in the @RequestBody @Validated Order order.
And then set @NotNull, @NotBlank